# python for loop to calculate mean value for each array segment

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I got a formal problem by using python and some `for` loops for each segment of my lists to be averaged.

1. I have an `array` of `x=(epochs, 257)`
2. Now I want to calculate for every `epoch` the mean value of the 257 values in there
3. The output should be an `array` of `x _ mean = (120, 1)`

I used a for loop, but the results are more than questionable.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean: `sum(arr)/len(arr)` ?

Comment: Why do you consider your results questionable?

Comment: x_mean=np.zeros (epochs, 1)                                                                    For i in range (0, epochs):                                                                      x_mean [i] = np.mean (x [i])      <---- that's my approach. ..I like to work with numpy more than using uncomfortable other stuff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
np.mean(x, axis=0)
```

is the solution, thanks for trying so hard. 
and thanks for posting comments just because.

Comment: Please use the `numpy` tag in your question next time in order to *emphasize* that you are interested in the numpy-based solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6]]
b = [float(sum(x))/len(x) for x in a]
```

Simply, you select all sublists and you calculate the average of each sublist in a standard way, e.g. sum/len.

The only potentially dangerous part is the divide operation. If the list contains only integers also the `sum` is integer. The `len` is integer automatically. Python 2 (in contrary to Python 3) uses integer-division when both numerator and denominator are integers so `2/3` -> 0. To prevent this we can convert e.g. the numerator to float.

Comment: Nope way to uncomfortable.... look up ...numpy and just use numpy.mean (x)     .....But I do like your approach. ..Thank you I think it is helpful....sometimes you Programm and miss the tree for the wood

Comment: after modifying your sugestion it fits in my code somehow...thank you for your help